# Component state doesn't change after action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

On startup I use `useEffect` to fetch some data from local storage. If the fetch was successful I want to send an action and change the state of the component. After dispatching the action, I see that the reducer received an action and returned the new state, but I don't see any change in the component when I try to log the new state. What can be the reason for this behaviour.

Here's the `action.ts`:

```
import {TOKEN_VALIDITY} from './actionTypes'

export const setTokenValidity = (isTokenValid: boolean) => ({ 
    type: TOKEN_VALIDITY,
    isTokenValid
})
```

Here's the `reducer.ts`:

```
    const auth = (state = false, action: any) => {
    
        // after dispatch I see this log in the console value is true
        console.log('auth reducer action type is ' + action.type + ' value is ' + action.isTokenValid) 
        
        switch(action.type) {
    
            case TOKEN_VALIDITY:
                return action.isTokenValid
    
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
    
    export default auth
```

In the component I want to update the state of isTokenValid, but I always get undefined for the value.

This is the component code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
let userToken = null;

const App = (props:any) => {

  useEffect(() => {

    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      try {
        userToken = await retrieveData('Token',null);    
        SplashScreen.hide();

        if(userToken != null) {
          props.setTokenValidity(true)
        }
        
        // this logs undefined for props.isTokenValid -- why???
        console.log("after token isValid: " + props.isTokenValid) 

        console.log('token ' + userToken);
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator >
    {!props.isTokenValid ? (
      <>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      </>
      
      ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator >  
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => ({
  setTokenValidity: (isTokenValid:boolean) => dispatch(setTokenValidity(isTokenValid))
})

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({
  isTokenValid: state.isTokenValid
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Do you reach istokenValid current state?

Comment: I think, you can use useSelector for functional components.

Comment: @İlker, I don't think I reach the current state at all. I always get undefined as output.

Comment: @Keselme `this logs undefined for props.isTokenValid -- why???` because you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). When the component re renders it'll get new props but your effect closes over props from a previous render. You have missing dependencies in your effect like `props.setTokenValidity` and the liner should have [told you that](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920), also the props.isTokenValid would be a missing dependency but no more if you remove the useless console.log that logs the stale closure.

Comment: @HMR what do you mean by - "You have missing dependencies in your effect like `props.setTokenValidity` "?

Comment: @Keselme That was explained [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#31-useeffect)

Answer (score 1):

In the first rendering, i.e. when the `useEffect` is fired and you call the method using `props.setTokenValidity` to set the token validity, the token gets set. However, the console also gets printed on the same rendering.

When the state gets updated and you get an updated one using the `props.isTokenValid`, this is the 2nd re-rendering(not the same rendering when useEffect was called) and the `useEffect` doesn't fire, therefore we don't see the console being printed with the new value.

If you for some reason want to log when `isTokenValid` is set, use another useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("after token isValid: " + props.isTokenValid) 

},[props.isTokenValid]);
```

Comment: It's possible to use multiple useEffets?

Comment: Yes, very much possible and it depends on use-cases. For example, on load API calls can be done on a useEffect with an empty array of dependencies which will be called only once and suppose any other side effect you want to run on a state or prop change can be written in another useeffect.

Comment: I tried to add another useEffect as you suggested, the output of the log was still undefined.

Comment: Then your isTokenValid is not getting updated correctly. You may want to create a minimal reproducible example. But rest assured, multiple useEffects are possible.

Comment: I tried to debug the code, and noticed that the second useEffect that you suggested got called only once, before I was able to dispatch the action. Should it be called again after the dispatch?

Comment: A useEffect with value in the dependencies array gets called every time the value in the dep array changes and also the first time when the component mounts. Here as you say it got called only once means it got called on component mounts. Now it will be called again only when the value of props.isTokenValid changes. If it's not getting called, then there is definitely a problem on how you are updating your store state.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers return a state object so you might wanna try doing this:

```
      switch(action.type) {
    
            case TOKEN_VALIDITY:
                return { ...state, isTokenValid: action.isTokenValid }
    
            default:
                return state
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it in my project, is by creating multiple useEffects.

In order to solve your problem you need to do 2 things:

1. You need to run `bootstrapAsync()`
2. You need to check **after bootstrapAsync finishes** for the data that was set into `userToken`

You have already did no.1 successfully, And your current problem is that your component does not updates when it receives new data, aka when `userToken` updates.

**The solution:**

Write another useEffect function which will be rendered 2 times: one time on component load(which we will ignore because the fetch isn't done yet) and another time when `userToken` value updates.

In order to avoid running our new useEffect on component load, we need to create a new state, which we will call allowNavigation.

`allowNavigation` prop will be set to true **only after the fetch is complete.**

Then, only when allowNavigation is set to `true`, we can check `userToken` and handle it properly.

The following code will help you:

```js
const App = (props:any) => {
  const [allowNavigate, setAllowNavigate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      try {
        userToken = await retrieveData('Token',null);    
        SplashScreen.hide();
        setAllowNavigate(true);
        ...
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allowNavigate)
        // this will now log the correct values
        console.log("after token isValid: " + props.isTokenValid) 
        console.log('token ' + userToken);
  }, [allowNavigate]);
...
```